# How do I open a Visual Basic when I start Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I find this code on [site](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/auto-open-macro/#Load_Form_Every_Time_Workbook_Opens).

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

It's not working.
I want to open «Visual Basic» after starting Excel then open the window `Module1` for example. Is it feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open the Virtual Basic Editor (VBE) on a specific module, try the following

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True
    Me.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: This code should work but I would suggest that OP should have a button (or maybe a menu option) to launch the form. I suspect that OP copied the code from somewhere but maybe his form is not called `UserForm1` and that's why it's not launching?

Comment: @Zac OP requests code to open up the VBE but is showing us code that should open up a UserForm. I don't think the latter is of any interest

Comment: I'm not suggestion that you haven't answered the question. I however am questioning OP's approach. Not sure why they would want to do this with code. Could open the editor with shortcut keys or excel **Developer** menu. Don't see why OP wants to do it this way

Comment: Maybe OP is tired of the very lengthy and difficult ALT+F11 shortcut each time he opens up his project WB

Comment: :).. I have no idea how to respond to that :D

Comment: Wait a minute! I'm tried this `Module1.Show` not working! @Tim Stack you're right! I'm testing lot of codes. But to work you need to reopen «Excel». I'm really tired to pressing on `ALT+F11`. Thanks for the code above.

Comment: @TimStack ··· This code does not work in the `.xlam` it works in `.xlsm`. Is it normal? What to do to work in all types of books?

Answer (score 1):

Note that Private Sub Workbook_Open() should be located in ThisWorkbook, not in a module, if so, then it's not being called.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to @TimStack:
(althought I do prefer his Method)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    SendKeys "%{F11}"
End Sub
```

Comment: `SendKeys` is iffy, causes a lot of issues. Especially when sending keys for the VBE, I have seen cases where people had their entire code deleted

Comment: @L8n This code is also working! But I'd better listen to our ··· Tim stack's code.

Comment: @L8n One more question to you! What if i open The default tab, i have my own tab called `My Macro`. I used this `SendKeys "%BP{F6}"` but it's not working! Also i put this code in `PERSONAL.XLSB` to work in all the books.. Not working  ···· Compile error:
Ambiguous name detected: Workbook.Open ···· I have other code with `Workbook_Open`. How to use it all together?